# TypeError: submitQuestion is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. Ihave the code:

```
function submitQuestion(){
var question = document.getElementById("questionSearchInput").value;
var email = document.getElementById("emailTextInput").value;
$.post("askQuestion.php", {"question":question, "email":email}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    location.href = "http://www.example.com/questionAsked.html";
});
}
```

I call the function off of a button, but get an error message returned

> "TypeError: submitQuestion is not a function"

I can't explain it, any ideas. I've used functions like this a million times and they all work. What could be different about this one.

Comment: How do you call the function? It may be just that submitQuestion is not in the scope at this time.

Comment: Are there any other errors in the browser console?

Comment: why would it not be in the scope. Browser say the function doesn't exist even though it's cearly defined in the html

Comment: @TomAlbanese, it may happen due to exception, or order of execution. Try using debugger (or simply insert `console.log('defining submitQuestion')` just before or after function definition) to find out the latter.

Comment: It won't let me do anything. Browser now just refreshes, when I try to do the onclick function. I put "console.log(submitQuestion())" in the onclick now the browser just refreshes.

Comment: it's calling the function a null reference in IE

Comment: now the function is firing as soon as page loads. without the onclick even being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it was because the button that fired the onclick had an id of submitQuestion. So the browser was a bit confused. I honestly wouldn't have thought that that would happen.